# Test Runs removed from deleted builds TFS

Tags: test-management, mtm, tfs2010

Maybe someone can tell me how this is actually supposed to work in TFS. We had it setup so that we would only retain the last four successful builds.

In Test Manager you put in a build you want to test against. So now all those test runs are tied to the build.

We changed the build retention policy to keep Test Results.

But whenever the build is removed all the Test Runs are deleted.

That seems to be something you really don't want to do??? Am I wrong?

Wasn't sure if this was the correct place for this or not.

Answer (score 1):

You've actually answered your own question here:

> In Test Manager you put in a build you want to test against. So now
>   all those test runs are tied to the build

TFS is designed so that there must be a build associated to a test run. In order to keep test results but not the build itself, you have a couple of options:

- Create a "dummy" build to run tests against. This requires coding against the TFS API.
- Run tests against a designated default build. This is available in later versions of TFS/Test Manager. I'm not sure if it's in 2010 or not.
- Export your test results to a report and save the report. This won't keep the test results themselves, but it will keep a record of what those results were.